# VSTS "web test" replay with fiddler2 log problem

Tags: visual-studio, testing

Does VSTS "web test" able to replay the same traffic (include the same response) which exported by Fiddler2?

It seems cannot because the goal of the "web test" is to check web application's functionality and performance.

And "web test" just replay the http request to web application.

Is my understand correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to export a fiddler session for use in VSTS web tests...

[Enhanced web test support in Fiddler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2007/04/17/enhanced-web-test-support-in-fiddler.aspx)